# Sending presigned url request on app close

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, vuejs3, pre-signed-url

In my Vue 3 app, I use `onbeforeunload` to detect when the app closed and in there I try to send presigned URL to my s3 bucket in AWS to save the file, but the file isn't saved.

I have tried: `axios.put(url, body, {content-type: application/json})`
This request is working when I call it inside the app, but not inside `onbeforeunload`.

I have also tried:-

```js
const headers = {type: 'application/json',};
const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(customerDashboard)], headers);
const res = navigator.sendBeacon(store.getters["vocabularyGameStore/getCustomerDashboardPresignedUrl"], blob);
```

which also doesn't work.

Comment: use 'beforeRouteLeave' of vue-roter or 'onBeforeUnmount' of vue (https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onbeforeunmount)

Comment: @LyuMir your solutions only work when navigating inside my app to another route, not when the tab is closed